# node.js rest api using express, multiple get scenarios for same resource

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am developing a rest api layer using node.js and express.  Let's say I have a resource called `message` that represents messages for a user logged into the system.  In my app.js file, I am defining a message route like this:

```
app.use("/message", require("./routes/message"));
```

and I am exposing routes for `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` in my `message.js` file.  I would like to have one `GET` that accepts the GUID of the message I would like to retrieve and another scenario where I need to allow someone to search and paginate that would generate a list of items returned.  I tried to add a new router.get scenario that would route to a `/list/:currentPage/:id` (id of the last record at the end of the list, would need to be optional for first page scenario), but the first get `/:Id` keeps getting called.  Is there a way to add multiple gets scenarios to a single "resource" file?  If not, would I have to create a whole new file, i.e., messages.js and add the extra get scenario there?

Comment: Please show representative examples of what paths you want to define unique routes for.  I can't really tell from your question what problem you're trying to solve.  A route handler for `/:Id` will match everything so you can't have that before other things you're trying to match.

Comment: I have two get scenarios, one that will get one particular resource, if I am just passing the id.  For the other scenario, I need to be able retrieve a list of resources with pagination in mind.  For the pagination scenario, I would like to use a combination of the last id from the previous record pull and get the next n results.

Comment: If you're asking your server to remember the last id, that's not a good idea.  Remember, you can have lots of users all making separate requests.  You can have the client pass in the last id and go from there.

Comment: The client will remember the last id from the previous list and send in the request.  I want the rest layer stateless.

Comment: Then, please answer my original question.  Show examples of the actual paths you want unique routes for.  I'm not sure why you ignored that as it will totally clarify the question.

Comment: Not ignoring at all, just not sure how to put it in the proper terms.  Let me try it like this:  /message for post, /message/:id for put, delete and get to return an individual resource.  /message/list/:id to retrieve a list of items by using the id to get n items greater than the id value.

Comment: Please show ACTUAL examples of the URL paths you want to support.  It shouldn't be hard at all. Not abstracted examples.  Not using the express parameter lingo. Actual examples of all the different forms of paths you want to uniquely target. That is required to design the right way to express the parameters in Express and order the handlers in Express so the greedy ones don't go first. Actual examples of paths please.  Add them to your question with an explanation by each separate example for what you want to parse out of it. 16hrs with no good answer is because your question is not clear.

Comment: I am a newbie to node.js so I am a little confused on how I should express the url paths.  The resource name is message.  I would like to access this resource using the standard rest verbs(post, put, delete and get).  My confusion is that I am not sure of what format this equates to in node.js.  I would like the following url paths to access the message resource: /message, /message/:id and /message/list/:id.  If this does not help, can you send a basic url path example so I can send you the right example?  I do apologize for being a newbie.

Comment: I think I am getting it.  So, if I am using express routing then I should define a new .js file called, for example, userList.js in my routing folder and add the get scenario for returning a list of items there.  Then add a new route to app.use that ties to this get scenario in the userList.js file.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make id optional `"/list/:currentPage/:id*?"`. Please do not forget to check id before using like

```
router.get("/list/:currentPage/:id*?", function (req,res) {
    var id = req.params.id
    if(id) {
        console.log('Now id can be used ', id)
    }
    res.send("ok")
});
```

I hope this help you

#### Alternate solution

If your id is not a number then you use following code

```
var listMessage = function (req, res) {
    console.log('id : ', req.params.id)
    console.log('currentPage : ', req.params.currentPage)
    res.send("ok")
}
router.get("/list/:currentPage([0-9]+)/:id*?", listMessage);
router.get("/list/:id", listMessage);
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I am looking for, the only additional caveat would be that I would expect either id or a combination of id and currentPage.  With that said it seems like I should make currentPage the optional field.  If it is just id, then this would be the scenario where I am looking for  a single record.  CurrentPage by itself or a combination of currentPage and id pertain to getting the next n records greater than id.

Comment: @user1790300 I have updated answer and added another solution that may help you.

Comment: So, if I am using express routing then I would need to create another js file and add the get list scenario there and then use app.use to tie the route to the new get scenario?

Comment: You may use separate file but you can also put into same file using `router.get` rather than using `app.get` or `app.use`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this a lot harder that it needs to be.

If what you're trying to do is to simply define routes for these urls:

```
/45
/message/45
/message/list/45
```

Where `45` is your id that you want to fetch from the URL, You don't show your relevant code, but if you're using an express router, you would define these routes in this order:

```
router.get("/message/list/:id", function(req, res) {
    res.send("/message/list " + req.params.id);
});
router.get("/message/:id", function(req, res) {
    res.send("/message "+ req.params.id);
});
router.get("/:id", function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params.id);
});

app.use(router);
```

There are no rules about what needs to be in what file so I don't know what that part of your question is about at all (particularly since you don't show any relevant code).  You can define routes all in one file or in multiple files, however your code is best organized.